# Application Insights – Capture ASMX WebMethod Names code not getting triggered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

In one of my assignment have to get web service method name in application insight.

i referenced below link
  https://unhandled.wordpress.com/2018/02/11/application-insights-capture-asmx-webmethod-names-invoked/

written below code in my class file.

```
public class ApplicationInsightsMethodLogInitializer: ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
            string soapActionMethod = null;
            string requestMethodName = null;
            string webServiceMethod = null;
            var logger = Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ILogger>();
            logger.Info("HI Pradeep Here");
            // Is this a TrackRequest() ?
            if (requestTelemetry == null) return;
            requestMethodName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["op"]; // Item("HTTP_SOAPACTION");
            if (requestMethodName == "" || requestMethodName == null)
            {
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo != null)
                {
                    requestMethodName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo;
                }
                if (requestMethodName != "" && requestMethodName != null)
                {
                    logger.Info("Got It..");
                    requestMethodName = requestMethodName.Replace("/", "");
                    // If we set the Success property, the SDK won't change it:
                    requestTelemetry.Success = true;
                    // Allow us to filter these requests in the portal:
                    requestTelemetry.Properties["WebMethodName"] = requestMethodName;
                    webServiceMethod = requestMethodName;
                }
            }
            if (webServiceMethod != null)
            {
                requestTelemetry.Context.Operation.Name = requestTelemetry.Context.Operation.Name.Replace("/" + webServiceMethod, "") + "/" + webServiceMethod;
            }
        }
```

Then register it in ApplicationInsights.config:

```
 <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    <Add Type="GCC.Foundation.Analytics.ApplicationInsightsMethodLogInitializer, GCC.Foundation.Analytics" />
```

While running code, in class file that code is not getting triggered and debugger is also not hitting.

Result should be like webserviceName/MethodName.

i tried to call this code from explicit calls its running because class method is called.

do i missed something in this, that's why ApplicationInsightsMethodLogInitializer is not getting triggered.

In all scenario dependency call getting logged in app insight, but mine changes not coming.

help me on this.

Comment: what's the assembly name?  and you can try register it in code, like in the Global.aspx.cs file -> Application_Start() method:  `TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new ApplicationInsightsMethodLogInitializer());`

Comment: where did you install the application insights? from visual studio menu option or via nuget? there is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52694066/problems-adding-insights-to-owin-based-project), you can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an asp.net mvc project, please install the application insights via right click the project name -> Configure application insights:
[image]

And please make sure that it registers correctly in ApplicationInsights.config, it should follow the rule below:

```
<Add Type "Fully qualified type name, assembly name"/>
```

Or you can you can instantiate the initializer in code, for example in Global.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {

     TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new MyTelemetryInitializer());
    }
```

For details please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer).

I tested it at my side either register in  ApplicationInsights.config, or in code, both work fine.

My Initializer sample:

```
namespace WebMVCStandard
{
    public class MyTelemetryInitializer:ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (!telemetry.Context.Properties.ContainsKey("Application123"))
            {
                telemetry.Context.Properties.Add("Application123", "todoxxxx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Register in ApplicationInsights.config:

```
<TelemetryInitializers>
  <Add Type ="WebMVCStandard.MyTelemetryInitializer,WebMVCStandard"/>
</TelemetryInitializers>
```

Or in code in the Global.aspx.cs:

```
namespace WebMVCStandard
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new MyTelemetryInitializer());
        }
    }
}
```

After execution, you can see the initializer class is hit on debug mode:
[image]

And also the new property is added after initializer class is called:
[image]

Comment: So happy it works for you. Could you please help mark it as answer, then it would be helpful for others.

Comment: my web services called from different server, so i want to get method name of the webservice in TelemetryInitializer.  Can you help me on that

Comment: yes, but it's better to submit a new post, so that if it's out of my scope, I can help escalate it.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, have created a new post.   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736480/capture-webservice-wcf-method-name-in-application-insight-calling-from-different)

Comment: could you please help mark this one as answer? thanks. I'm working on the new issue now.